# Unable to consume Rgba<u8> (no methods) in Rust

Tags: image, rust

```
let png = image::open("src/heightmaps/ALPSMLC30_N050E014_DSM_8_BIT.png").unwrap();
    for p in png.pixels() {
        let p: image::Rgba<u8> = p.2;
    }
```

p is `(u32, u32, image::Rgba<u8>)`. What I don't know is how to access the `u8` out of `Rgba` (the VSCode doesn't find any methods for it). How do I proceed? Here is the link to the Rgba struct: https://docs.rs/image/0.23.13/image/struct.Rgba.html.

Comment: As per documentation, it is a tuple struct. `p.2.0` should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

image::Rgba is a tuple struct, you can access fields of a tuple struct using `struct.0` syntax or more ergonomically through destructuring:

```rust
let png = image::open("src/heightmaps/ALPSMLC30_N050E014_DSM_8_BIT.png").unwrap();
for (_, _, image::Rgba(p)) in png.pixels() {
    let [r, g, b, a] = p;
}
```

Comment: You could go as far as `for (_, _, image::Rgba([r, g, b, a])) in png.pixels()`.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the definition for [`image::Rgba<T>`](https://docs.rs/image/0.23.13/image/struct.Rgba.html), it appears that the only field is public so you should be able to just access it directly.

E.g. with verbsoe destructuring:

```
let png = image::open("src/heightmaps/ALPSMLC30_N050E014_DSM_8_BIT.png").unwrap();
for p in png.pixels() {
    let p: image::Rgba<u8> = p.2;
    let rgba: [u8;4] = p.0;
    let [r,g,b,a] = rgba;

}
```

Comment: @Ivan C's answer is in my opinion more idiomatic.